# Ajax json data with appendchild to html page

Tags: ajax, json, appendchild

I'm new to jquery/ajax/javascript. I try to get data from an API, everything works, except, I can't print the data to my html-page. Somehow the appendChild-method doesn't work. What do I do wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
function openkvk() {
        var urls = "https://overheid.io/api/kvk?";
        var keyset = {
            "ovio-api-key": '041be6bc5818ad9bfe0ff9c9a9637a24b2fd1ec817cd8c3d102f61afc8006dd2'
        };

        var postcode = document.getElementById('plaats').value;
        var naam = document.getElementById('bedrijfsnaam').value;
        var kvk = document.getElementById('kvk').value;

        console.log("tot aan hier1");
            if(postcode != ""){
                urls = urls + "&filters[postcode]=" + postcode;
            }
            if(naam != ""){
                urls = urls + "&filters[handelsnaam]=" + naam;
            }
            if(kvk != ""){
                urls = urls + "&filters[dossiernummer]=" + kvk;
            }
        console.log("tot aan hier2");

       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: urls,
            headers:{"ovio-api-key":'041be6bc5818ad9bfe0ff9c9a9637a24b2fd1ec817cd8c3d102f61afc8006dd2',"Content-Type":"application/json"},
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(data) {

                var response = data.responseJSON;
                console.log(response);

                var container = document.getElementById('result-kvk');
                container.innerHTML = "";

                console.log(data);
                console.log("data geprint");

                $.each(response._embedded.rechtspersoon, function(index,item){
                    console.log(item);
                    console.log("items geprint");

                    var kvknummer = document.createElement("P");
                    kvknummer.innerHTML = item.dossiernummer;
                    //console.log(kvknummer);

                    var handelsnaam = document.createElement('P');
                    handelsnaam.innerHTML = item.handelsnaam;
                    console.log("hwiueh");

                    //failed
                    container.appendChild(kvknummer);
                    container.appendChild(handelsnaam);
                });   
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your container is valid?  Maybe console.log it to make sure?

Comment: Thanks! Yes the container is valid, that's what makes this a weird problem for me.